# split() function for '$' not working

Tags: java

I'm doing a simple code

```
String splitString = "122$23$56$rt";
for(int i=0;i<splitString.split("$").length;i++){
   System.out.println("I GOT IS :: "+splitString.split("$")[i]);
}
```

When I split like

```
splitString.split("$")
```

It is giving me output `[122$23$56$rt]`

Why this is not splinting on '$'?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`String.split()` takes in **regex** as argument and `$` is a metacharacter in `Java regex API`. Therefore, you need to escape it:

```
String splitString = "122$23$56$rt";
for(int i=0;i<splitString.split("\\$").length;i++){
   System.out.println("I GOT IS :: "+splitString.split("\\$")[i]);
}
```

Other metacharacters supported by the `Java regex API` are: `<([{\^-=!|]})?*+.>`

Answer (score 16):

```
split(Pattern.quote("$"))
```

Is my favorite.

See [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.

Your code doesn't work because `$` has a special meaning in regex, and since [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a *regex* as an argument, the `$` is not interpreted as the String `"$"`, but as the special [meta character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `$`.

Answer (score 8):

Escape it. the `split()` method takes a regex: `split("\\$")`

Answer (score 4):

try something like this

```
String splitString = "122$23$56$rt";
for(int i=0;i<splitString.split("\\$").length;i++){
   System.out.println("I GOT IS :: "+splitString.split("$")[i]);
}
```

NOTE: [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression.

Your regular expression uses a special character ie `$`

`$` is the regular expression for "end of line".

Answer (score 3):

```
String splitString = "122$23$56$rt";
for(int i=0;i<splitString.length;i++){
   System.out.println("Now you GOT this :: "+split(Pattern.quote("$")));
}
```

There are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), and the opening square bracket [, the opening curly brace {, These special characters are often called "metacharacters".

So your `$` is also `metacharacter` as defination says so you can't split using simple function. Though you must use `pattern` in this case.

Thanks..

Comment: +1, but please provide an explanation with the answer.

Comment: Now that's an explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Escape it like

```
split("\\$")
```

instead of split("$")

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()`, `.match()`, `.replaceAll()` are some of the methods that use RegEx pattern and so you should look at the javadoc of the [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

If your splitting character happen to be one of the pattern characters, you must escape it with `\\`, in this case your split call should be: `.split("\\$")`

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because split() takes input as RegEx

```
String splitString = "122$23$56$rt";
for(int i=0;i<splitString.split("\\$").length;i++){
System.out.println("I GOT IS :: "+splitString.split("\\$")[i]);
}
```